# Are xy and x/y open maps?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to solve Milner-stasheff characteristic classes problem 1(B) which is on page 11 of the book.
First I took family of $(n+1)$ charts $$h_i: \mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{RP}^n$$ given by $$h_i(x)=[(x_1,\dots,x_{i-1},1,x_i,\dots,x_n)]$$
In order to proof the topology induced by the Atlas on $\mathbb{RP}^n$ is indeed the quotient topology, I am trying out ways to prove $$q:\mathbb R^{n+1}-\{0\}\to \mathbb{RP}^n$$ is an open map. For that given any $U\subseteq \mathbb R^{n+1}-\{0\}$ taking $$U_1=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n+1})\vert x_1\neq 0\}$$
$\vdots$
$$U_{n+1}=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n+1})\vert x_{n+1}\neq 0\}$$
$$U=U_1\cup\cdots\cup U_{n+1}$$
defining (n+1) maps as $$p_i:U_i\longrightarrow \mathbb R^n$$ given by$$P_i(x_1,\cdots, x_{n+1})=(\frac{x_1}{x_i},\cdots, \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_i})$$
Then $$q(U)=\cup_{i=1}^{n+1} h_i(p_i(U_i)))$$
Hence, the question boils down to $p_i(U_i)$ is open in $\mathbb R^n$ or not
This motivated me to ask the the question below?
Let
$$\begin{align}f\colon\mathbb{R}^2&\to \mathbb{R} \qquad & g\colon \mathbb{R} \times (\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}) \to \mathbb{R}\\ (x,y)&\mapsto xy &(x,y)\mapsto \frac{x}{y}\end{align}$$

Are $f$ and $g$ open maps? If they are not, could you give me a hint for a counter example?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: @KaushikKhamari the question is clear. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please take a look at our suggestions for [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), with emphasis on [providing context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). Your question is entirely lacking context which you could easily provide: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck? What question can you formulate regarding your attempts? Without such context, your post is a bare problem statement, and such posts can easily attract down votes and close votes.

Comment: @LeeMosher, is the context clear? Sorry, it got a little long.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, these are open maps. It suffices to show that basic open sets are taken to open sets. Note that for $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus 0$, $x \mapsto yx$ is a homemorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. So if $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ is open then $g(U \times V) = \bigcup_{y \in V} \frac1yU$ is a union of open sets hence open. Now suppose $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}$ are open. If $0 \notin V$ then $f(U \times V) = \bigcup_{y \in V} yU$ is open. Similarly if $0 \notin U$. If $0 \in U \cap V$ then
$$f(U \times V) = f(U \times (V \setminus 0)) \cup \{0\} = f(U \times (V \setminus 0))$$
is open since $V$, being open, cannot equal $\{0\}$.